# Как в python создать вектор структур?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно создать многомерный массив/таблицу в Python. Многомерный массив мне не подходит, т к я хочу хранить разные типы данных. В C++ я бы мог просто использовать вектор структур, а как подобное сделать на python? Знаю, есть `PrettyTable`, но я хочу ещё по возможности менять данные в массиве. `SQLite` - выбор хороший, но я хочу избежать записи на диск. Т е программа создаёт таблицу и работает с ней из памяти. Хранить на диске ничего не нужно.

Версия python: 3.10.5

Comment: Питону всё-равно какие вы данные в списке храните. Список может быть многомерным. `PrettyTable` вроде для отображения данных в основном, а не для хранения. Ещё есть очень удобная библиотека `Pandas`, но это для двумерных таблиц, если у вас больше измерений, то не подойдёт.